# What will happen when an empty set involved in a expression?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Let $g(x)=h(x)+\sum_{k\in\mathcal{K}}f(x,k)$ where $\mathcal{K}$ is a set with finite number of elements. My question is when $\mathcal{K}$ is an empty set, then what is $g(x)$? Is $g(x)$ will be undefined or $g(x)=h(x)$?  I am confused in the scenario where an expression involving a set. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any sum over the empty set

$$\sum_{x \in \varnothing} F(x)$$

is equal to zero by definition, so $g(x) = h(x)$ if $\mathcal{K} = \varnothing$.

---

Answer to the comment: $\displaystyle \prod_{x \in \varnothing} F(x)$ is defined as $1$, $\max \varnothing$ and $\min \varnothing$ don't exist. In specific situations we may abuse the notation and write $\max \varnothing = -\infty$, $\min \varnothing = +\infty$.

Generally suppose we have an associative, commutative binary operation $\ast$ on elements of some set $S$. For a finite, non-empty $A = \{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \} \subseteq S$ and arbitrary function $F : S \to S$ we can define

$$\DeclareMathOperator*{\op}{\LARGE \ast} \op \limits_{x \in A} F(x) = F(a_1) \ast F(a_2) \ast \ldots \ast F(a_n).$$

It's then reasonable to define $\op \limits_{x \in \varnothing} F(x)$ to be the neutral element of $\ast$ (provided that one exists), because in that case the following rule, which holds for all non-empty finite sets $A \subseteq S$, will continue to hold with $A$ empty:

> Suppose $A \subseteq S$ is finite and $b \in S \setminus A$. Then
>
> $$\op \limits_{x \in A \cup \{ b \}} F(x) = \left[ \op \limits_{x \in A } F(x) \right] \ast F(b).$$

That justifies the definition of the product over the empty set to be $1$. As for $\min$ and $\max$ as operations on $\mathbb{R}$, they don't have neutral elements, so they are not defined on the empty set. However, we can extend the order $(\mathbb{R}, \leqslant)$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \}$ so that $-\infty < a < +\infty$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the extended order $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ has the greatest element $+\infty$, which becomes the neutral element of $\min$, so it makes sense to define $\min \varnothing = +\infty$ and similarly, $\max \varnothing = -\infty$.

Comment: What about other operations over an empty set? For example,  $\max$, $\min$, $\prod$.

Comment: @Dave If $s=\max S$ where $S$ is a set then $s\in S$. This is not possible for $S=\varnothing$ so $\max\varnothing$ is not defined. Same story for $\min$. Further $\sum_{x\in\varnothing}x$ and $\prod_{x\in\varnothing}x$ both correspond
with neutral elements wrt certain operations. The first neutral wrt
what commonly is called addition (hence is often denoted as $0$),
the second neutral wrt what is commonly called multiplication (hence
is often denoted as $1$).

Comment: @Dave I've edited my post to answer your question.

Comment: If $\max S$ is defined then **always** $\max S\in S$. So I disagree with $\min\varnothing=+\infty$ and $\max\varnothing=-\infty$. We have situations where $\inf\varnothing=+\infty$ and $\sup\varnothing=-\infty$.

Comment: @drhab I wrote that $\max$ and $\min$ of $\varnothing$ formally don't exist and in certain situations we abuse the notation and write $\min \varnothing = \infty$ and $\max \varnothing = -\infty$. After all, it's only a convention, and if you would like me to, I can think of some realistic situation where it would be useful. Also, by definition $\inf \varnothing = \max \{ a \in \mathbb{R} : (\forall b \in \varnothing) \, a \leqslant b \} = \max \mathbb{R}$ so $\max \mathbb{R} \notin \mathbb{R}$ if we assume (which you agreed with in some situations :p) that $\inf \varnothing = +\infty$.

Comment: On e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements) you will find: "a maximal element of a subset S of some partially ordered set (poset) **is an element of S**...". And $\mathbb R$ simply has no maximal element. I have never encountered the abuse of notation that you speak of. From here I will stop trying to convince you, though. Cheers.